# php function bucle array_map

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have this price list:

```
$price_canvas_001 = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array(786, $item->product->category_ids)? (4.55 * $item->qty) + 2.45 : 0;},$request->all_items));
$price_canvas_002 = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array(787, $item->product->category_ids)? (4.55 * $item->qty) + 2.45 : 0;},$request->all_items));
$price_canvas_003 = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array(788, $item->product->category_ids)? (5.55 * $item->qty) + 3.45 : 0;},$request->all_items));
$price_canvas_004 = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array(789, $item->product->category_ids)? (5.55 * $item->qty) + 3.45 : 0;},$request->all_items));
$price_canvas_005 = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array(790, $item->product->category_ids)? (5.55 * $item->qty) + 3.45 : 0;},$request->all_items));
$price_canvas_006 = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array(791, $item->product->category_ids)? (6.00 * $item->qty) + 5.00 : 0;},$request->all_items));
$price_canvas_007 = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array(792, $item->product->category_ids)? (6.00 * $item->qty) + 5.00 : 0;},$request->all_items));
$price_canvas_008 = array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array(793, $item->product->category_ids)? (7.00 * $item->qty) + 6.00 : 0;},$request->all_items));
$price_canvas_009 = $price_canvas_001 + $price_canvas_002 + $price_canvas_003 + $price_canvas_004 + $price_canvas_005 + $price_canvas_006 + $price_canvas_007 + $price_canvas_008;
```

And I tried to make it more efficient, creating this loop:

```
function granTotal(){
    $category_id = array(786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793 );
    $increase = array(4.55, 4.55, 5.55, 5.55, 6.55, 6.00, 7.00 );
    $base = array(2.45, 2.45, 3.45, 3.45, 3.45, 5.00, 5.00, 6.00 );
    $length = count($category_id);
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
        array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return in_array($category_id[$i], $item->product->category_ids)? ($increase[$i] * $item->qty) + $base[$i] : 0;},$request->all_items));
        $total += category_id[$i];
    }
    return $total;
}


$total = granTotal();
echo $total;
```

But it doesn't work. Please what's wrong?

Comment: `category_id[$i]` < did you forget to add the `$` to this, for `category_id` that is?

Comment: What is "bucle"? I don't understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems. Firstly, you have a number of variables that are not in scope where you are trying to use them: `$request` in `granTotal`, and `$category_id`, `$increase`, `$base` and `$i` in your anonymous function. Secondly, you are not actually summing all the results from your calls to `array_sum`. Try this:

```
function granTotal($request){
    $category_id = array(786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793 );
    $increase = array(4.55, 4.55, 5.55, 5.55, 6.55, 6.00, 7.00 );
    $base = array(2.45, 2.45, 3.45, 3.45, 3.45, 5.00, 5.00, 6.00 );
    $length = count($category_id);
    $total = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
        $total += array_sum(array_map(function ($item) use($category_id, $increase, $base, $i) {
            return in_array($category_id[$i], $item->product->category_ids) ? ($increase[$i] * $item->qty) + $base[$i] : 0; }, 
                            $request->all_items));
    }
    return $total;
}


$total = granTotal($request);
echo $total;
```